# How can I fix "DllRegisterServer entry point was not found" errors on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, dll

When I execute `regsvr32 inetcomm.dll` from Start > Run, I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions? I am using Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

I am using Outlook 2007 and have configured my mail... it only works sometimes. I can receive mails without any problems but sending is the issue: when my sending fails it says:

> Sending reported error "0x800ccc60"

When I searched for my Outlook failure one of the articles said I should run
the following line: `regsvr32.exe inetcomm.dll`.

Outlook 2007 works pretty well for me in XP but not in Windows 7. Any ideas why this might be? I think it is because of `inetcomm.dll`... see the link below which demonstrates my problem:

> http://www.outlookpower.com/issues/issue200608/00001838001.html

When I try to send mail I get this error:

[image]

When I searched for inetcomm.dll in my system I got these two:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there is probably a deeper problem that you are trying to fix.  Why are you trying to register this DLL?

Comment: The instructions you got must have been a bit old.  On my Windows XP boxt `inetcomm.dll` does export `DllRegisterServer`, however on Windows 7 it does not, hence the errors when trying to register on Windows 7.  How about describing your Outlook configuration.  What SMTP are you trying to connect to?  Who is your ISP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in your screen capture:

```
451 Exploitable Server
See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?117.197.185.192
```

I went to the URL. I got this message:

```
Database of vulnerable/hacked servers
Address and Port:   117.197.185.192
Record Created: Mon Dec 28 22:59:36 2009 GMT
Record Updated: Mon Dec 28 22:59:36 2009 GMT
Additional Information: Spam Sending Trojan or Proxy attempted to send mail from/to from=<ordinarilyuc9@vancouverislandwomenssports.com> to=<belial@paticipating.domain> proto=esmtp helo=<bntxwxq>
Currently active and flagged to be published in DNS
If you wish to request a delisting please do so through the Support System.
```

What this says to me is that your SMTP server is a known vulnerable server. Outlook is protecting you.

Instead of trying to reinstall Outlook, you should consider using a separate SMTP server before jumping to conclusions. Seriously.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Randolph Is there any other way other that using seperate smtp server... Because i reply to all my mails through my domain mail Id...
Can i ask for help from my server incharge person...

Comment: @pandiya there is probably not much you can do.  Your ISP is likely the one returning that message.  I would suggest talking with them, or having the the maintainers of the SMTP server contact your ISP and request to be unblocked.  Sorbs also has a link if you follow the link in the error message to request that a record be corrected.

Comment: If you don't have your own domain name, I'd suggest getting one (you can go through GoDaddy or similar). Then sign up with Google Apps for your Domain (the Standard one, which is free of charge). There you can manage your mail via Google Mail (identical to Gmail but it's with your own domain name). If necessary, you can still continue using Outlook, and use Google as your POP3 and SMTP servers, or online like Gmail.

Comment: My pleasure! If you can avoid reinstalling any Office product, it's worth the effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

inetcomm.dll doesn't export a DLLRegisterServer function.

Have you tried preventing regsvr32 from calling DLLRegisterServer by using the /n and /i parameters?

```
regsvr32 /n /i inetcomm.dll
```

Comment: @Affine same error.... Please help me out.... Outlook 2007 sends mail sometimes and fails sometimes and it is because of inetcomm.dll..

Comment: Seems unlikely your intermittant fault could be related to registering a DLL. Could some other process be interrupting it? Have you tried temporarily disabling your anti-virus software's e-mail scanner? You may also need to check all occurances of inetcomm.dll on your system are the same version.

Comment: @Affine i ve done the former process but didnt do the latter one...
I ll let u know after checking it out....

Comment: How do you know the failure is because of inetcomm.dll?

Comment: @Stephen - it isn't, and I think you've spotted that. See my answer.