# How to do a Detect and Repair in outlook 2007?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have been having issues with outlook 2007 sending mails. I want to detect and repair it.

I haven't been able to find it. The only thing I have found is Office Diagnostics and that doesn't help a bit. How do I run Detect and Repair?

Comment: What exactly is wrong? You might be overreacting to the problem.

Comment: @Randolph look at my previous question http://superuser.com/questions/110799/how-to-fix-dllregisterserver-entry-point-was-not-found-error-windows-7

Comment: I've responded there. I don't think this is related to Outlook at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Control Panel open Add/Remove Programs.  Select Office 2007 and click the  Change button  Select Repair and follow the prompts

Answer (score 0):

I recently had sending issues with Outlook 2003.

I repaired my installation of Outlook 2003 using the install cd. I just ran the set up. One of the options was to do a repair.

It's probably the same for 2007

Ak

Answer (score 0):

If your PST file is corrupted and you want to repair it, you can use Microsoft Inbox repair Tool (SCANPST.exe). As for Outlook 2007 location of this inbox repair tool is :

`MS Outlook 2007: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office1`

If you are unable to apply this method, then read a similar [topic](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=339316) will help you to do your task securely.